# Wordpress split at more-tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I tried separating the content of an article before the `<!--more-->` Tag from the rest in Wordpress.

I have two columns:

- on the left side including the entry-title and a "sub-title" consisting of everything BEFORE the `<!--more-->` Tag.
- on the right side the article excluding everything before the `<!--more-->` Tag.

I used the following code to separate both parts:
This is the "sub-title"

```
<h2><?php global $more; $more=0; the_content(''); $more=1; ?></h2>
```

This is the rest of the article.

```
<?php the_content( '', true ); ?>
```

Everything works, but I have two artifacts left.

- the "sub-title" is wrapped in `<p class="p1">...text...</p>`
- in the article there is this `<p><span id="more-15"></span></p>`

How can I get rid of the artifacts? I really have now idea and they are screwing with my layout.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to get you going.

```
<?php
//Output sub-title
global $more;
$more = 0;
$out = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content('') );
$out = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $out );
$out = strip_tags( $out, '<br><a><em><u><strong>' ); //may need to add more tags
echo '<h2>'.$out.'</h2>';
$more = 1;
?>

<?php
//Output content
$out = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content('', TRUE ) );
$out = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $out );
$repl = '<p><span id="more-' . get_the_ID() . '"></span></p>';
$out = str_replace($repl, '', $out);
echo $out;
?>
```

A better approach would be to make these as filters for `the_content`, but without knowing your whole site structure, this could introduce other layout errors.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it works. However, there is a "more"-link added to the subtitle. Is there a way to not show it.
And how would the filter thing with `the_content` work?

Comment: Adding an empty string to 'get_the_content()` like you had in your original example should suppress this. I edited my code to show this. For filters, you can start down that rabbit hole by [reading this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)